# How to dynmically make a cell editable in jqGrid PHP

Tags: jqgrid-php

I have a jqGrid PHP project where I have been able with the below code to make rows background color and editable = false, based on the value of a cell in that row.

```
$rowattr = <<<ROWATTR
function (rd) {   
    if (rd.br_re_ending == "OTFN") {
        return { "style": "background-color:#FF9999; background-image:none;", "editable": false };
    }
}
ROWATTR;

$grid->setGridEvent('rowattr', $rowattr);
```

What I am now trying to do is to similarly use the value of a cell to determine if another cell in that same row should be editable or not. I have tried several options like the below, but with no avail.

```
$rowattr = <<<ROWATTR
function (rd) {   
    if (rd.br_ch_flag_extrameals == "STD") {
    return { "setColProp", "br_ch_ch2_mon", "editable": True };  
    }
}
ROWATTR;

$grid->setGridEvent('rowattr', $rowattr);
```

Can someone please provide some help or guidance in how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Adri

Comment: I recommend you to ask the owner of the product - Guriddo - i.e [Guriddo Support](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4)

Comment: Thanks Tony. I tried logging in into the Forums yesterday and I got the following error: Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server.

Comment: Please post this problem to the support of Guriddo Support. In the site there is a email regarding this. Thank you.